# How to pull the whole row which has the latest date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’m trying to select the pair of product – distribution center attached with the most recent order (based on order date). For one order I can have multiple products, but the whole order will be shipped from one specific distribution center.
How do I select the specific product-distribution center attached with the latest order? 
My structure is basically like this:

`data.orderdetail` table has `ordernum`, `orderdate`, `distributioncenter`

I tried to pull like this, but it doesn’t give me the desired result. I’m using sql server 2008:

```
SELECT DISTINCT y.OrderNum, y.Product, y.DistributionCenter
              , CAST(y.OrderDate AS DATE) AS Orderdate
FROM         (SELECT   OrderNum, MAX(CAST(Orderdate AS date)) AS orderdate
                       FROM  data.OrderDetail
                       GROUP BY OrderNum) AS x 
INNER JOIN data.OrderDetail AS y 
ON y.OrderNum = x.OrderNum
```

Comment: You would essentially have to order by orderdate in descending order to get the most recent entries

Comment: ORDER BY orderdate LIMIT 1

Comment: What is the desired result and what is wround with the correct result?

Comment: Why upvote a comment which is invalid T-SQL? `LIMIT`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you need one more clause in your join Condition

You've got

```
ON y.OrderNum = x.OrderNum
```

Which will return all the orders that match the Order number in the subquery

But you'll need

```
ON y.OrderNum = x.OrderNum
AND y.OrderDate = x.orderdate
```

Which will return all the orders that match the Order number in the subquery and the maximum date for that order number

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
y.OrderNum, 
y.Product, 
y.DistributionCenter, 
CAST(y.OrderDate AS DATE) AS Orderdate 
FROM (
     SELECT 
     OrderNum, 
     MAX(CAST(Orderdate AS date)) AS orderdate 
     FROM data.OrderDetail 
     GROUP BY OrderNum
     ) AS x 
INNER JOIN 
data.OrderDetail AS y 
ON y.OrderNum = x.OrderNum
AND y.OrderDate = x.orderdate
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is row_number. This will partition your result set by OrderNum then rank the sets by the OrderDate. You can then filter off the extra rows in another where clause.

```
select result.*,
    CAST(result.OrderDate as date) as Orderdate,
from (
    select y.*,
        row_number() over (
            partition by y.OrderNum order by CAST(y.OrderDate as date) desc
            ) rank_
    from (
        select OrderNum,
            MAX(CAST(Orderdate as date)) as orderdate
        from data.OrderDetail
        group by OrderNum
        ) as x
    inner join data.OrderDetail as y on y.OrderNum = x.OrderNum
    ) result
where result.rank_ = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks guy, but for some reason it still pops up a whole bunch of orders associated with that product-distribution center. I only want to return the latest ordernum.

Comment: So are you looking for only one order to be returned?

Comment: hi Will, yes, only the most recent order for a pair of product-distribution center.thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT OrderNum, Product, DistributionCenter, OrderDate 
       , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by OrderNum order by OrderDate  desc) as rownum
    FROM OrderDetail
)  as xxx
where xxx.rownum = 1
```

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
; WITH CTE1
AS (
    SELECT
        od.OrderNum
        , od.Product
        , od.DistributionCenter
        , CAST(od.OrderDate AS DATE) AS OrderDate
        , RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY od.Product, od.DistributionCenter ORDER BY CAST(od.OrderDate AS DATE) DESC)
    FROM data.OrderDetail od
)
SELECT
    OrderNum
    , Product
    , DistributionCenter
    , OrderDate
FROM CTE1
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```